# filter contact names and remove email addresses

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

I am using Filter with ListView which is populated trough Contact data which contains Names and Number.

Now i got two problems when i type a text into `EditText` which in turns fires  `adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString())`

> 1) When i type 'aa' latter (in my code )
>
> i can see name starting from 'aa' for example aakruti , but at the
>   same time i am able to view email addresses too , which i don't wanted
>   to make it visible when a filter is fired.

[image]

> 2) When i type 'aa' latter (in phone's inbuilt contact list)
>
> i can see name starting from 'aa' for example aakruti
>
> but i am missing one name i.e. S A T Y A ( which is shown by contact
>   search when i type 'aa' latter into it )

[image]

here is my filter query , inside `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`

```
StringBuilder buffer = null;
String[] args = null;
    if (constraint != null) {
    buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append("UPPER(");
    buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
    args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
    }
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
System.out.println(buffer);
return mContent.query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
            projection,
            buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(), 
            args,sortOrder
);
```

projection data

```
   public static String[] projection = new String[] {
           ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
           ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME

   };
```

**EDIT**

So far i tried to access

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME
```

But GIVEN_NAME displays few `email address` too and even it shows `contact name which has email address`

for example ,

```
xyz@gmail.com 
Raul Jakson          (which only has email address no contact number)
Raul Jakson          ( i see this name twice as it has two different email address , but i wanna see it as name )
```

so can anyone tell me how can i limit the email addresses and show only NAMES which has only contact phone numbers ?

Comment: Regarding the email address problem, I don't think you are doing anything wrong.  It's probably just the way Android contacts work.  If you really want to exclude emails, then you could add another clause to your SQL to say something like `buffer.append(" AND " +  ContactsContract.Contacts.FAMILY_NAME + " NOT LIKE '%@%');`

Comment: @1ka well okay , as i searched in a android then i came to know that the above repeatation is because of `Joined Contacts` but in a contact list i can see Raul Jakson as one so how can i make it a one entity just like contact does

Comment: Try including the contact ID (_ID) and filtering on that, either via code or using a UNIQUE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the emails show up because that contact has no name.  In these cases, Android will use the email as the display name.  To avoid showing these, use GIVEN_NAME and FAMILY_NAME.  See the [api docs for StructuredName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html).

Secondly, you don't find SATIYA as your query is looking for a DISPLAY_NAME that begins with AA.  SATIYA is not a word, it's a sequence of initials, e.g. S A T I Y A.  If you want to find these, then you'll have to craft your query to cater for this.  You could search for *A*A*, but you'll probably get many others hits too.  I suspect Android is doing some variant of an initial+surname search where **BO** would find Barack Obama.

Comment: Thanks for informative reply , do you know how to write initial+surname constraint ?

Comment: Try this.  It uses SUBSTR to take the first inital and || to concatenate the family name:
`buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("UPPER(SUBSTR(");
buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.GIVEN_NAME);
buffer.append(",1,1)) || ");
buffer.append("UPPER(");
buffer.append(ContactsContract.Contacts.FAMILY_NAME);
buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
`

Comment: You can find more on the SQLITE syntax from [their website](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).